# How to use Accessibility Permission in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, accessibility, android-permissions

These are the codes I wrote to show the lock screen to the user when opening a locked app in my app locker app. It works without any problem. But there is a small problem.

- For example, if I lock WhatsApp, every time I open WhatsApp, I see the lock screen. But when I unlock the lock and chat with someone, I use emojis. When I go to the place where I want to select emoji, I see the lock screen on WhatsApp. It is a problem for the user. For another example, if someone sends me a photo, when I touch on that photo in WhatsApp, I see the lock screen. I saw this only on WhatsApp. In many other apps, this kind of lock screen is shown to the user at unnecessary times.

So it causes trouble for the user. Please help me to solve that problem.

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService; 
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo; 
import android.app.Notification; 
import android.app.PendingIntent; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat; 
import com.coremora.secure.MainActivity; 
import com.coremora.secure.R; 
import com.coremora.secure.lockScreens.PatternLockScreen;   
import com.coremora.secure.lockScreens.PinCodeLockScreen; 
import static com.coremora.secure.MainActivity.dbPackage; 
import static com.coremora.secure.MainActivity.pass; 
import static com.coremora.secure.MainActivity.passType; 
import static com.coremora.secure.MainActivity.updateData; 

public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService { 

static String secondApp = ""; 

public static void getAppAndLock(Context context, AccessibilityEvent event) { 

    String topActivity = event.getPackageName() + ""; 
    if (secondApp.equals(context.getPackageName()) || secondApp.equals(topActivity) || topActivity.equals(context.getPackageName())) { 
    } else { 
        for (String currentPackage : dbPackage) { 
            if (topActivity.equals(currentPackage)) { 
                if (!pass.equals("")) { 
                    if (passType.equals("pin")) { 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PinCodeLockScreen.class); 
                        intent.putExtra("packageName",topActivity); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                        context.startActivity(intent); 
                    } else { 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PatternLockScreen.class); 
                        intent.putExtra("packageName", topActivity); 
                       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                        context.startActivity(intent); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    secondApp = topActivity; 
} 

@Override 
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) { 

    getAppAndLock(this, event); 
} 

@Override 
public void onServiceConnected() { 
    updateData(this); 
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo(); 
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED; 
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN; 
    this.setServiceInfo(info); 
} 

@Override 
public void onInterrupt() { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Interrupt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 

@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE); 

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.CHANNEL_ID) 
            .setContentTitle("App Lock") 
            .setContentText("App Lock service started") 
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon) 
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) 
            .build(); 

    startForeground(1, notification); 
    return START_STICKY; 
  } 
}
```